# Difference between astronomy and astrophysics

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, terminology

In my university, the department for [astronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy) and [astrophysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysics) are distinct. I want to know what's basically the difference between the two fields?

Comment: maybe best suited for http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Although these questions are off-topic, but check this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148203/.

Comment: See also the tag wikis for [astronomy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/astronomy/info) and [astrophysics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/astrophysics/info). (I personally edited much of that info in, but I think they do a fair job of representing the field's opinions. But really the terms are often interchangeable.)

Answer (score 1):

Astronomy is mostly concerned with observing the night sky, calculating the positions and movements of the heavenly bodies and identifying objects.

Astrophysics is concerned with figuring out how stars form, studying the chemical reactions within the stars, calculating what elements the stars contain and so on.